# Why it will cause Bad file descriptor error when call close() and dup2()/read() in different threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, system-calls

Here is the strace log file. Can someone explain to me what happeded to the fd 8?
[image]
How can I avoid this situation?

I want to know what's wrong with my code and how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the issue. It is because thread 143504 close the fd 8 twice. Before the second call to close(), another thread 143505 already created the new fd 8.